How to mock AG Grid API - forEachNode
I want to test my implementation which I have inside forEachNode but my test is not going inside forEachNode loop or the mockImplementation.
I'm using Jest and React Testing Library.
Code I want to test:
const validateIfEmptyEditableCells = (
    event: CellEditingStoppedEvent,
    editableColumnsList: string[]
) => { 
    event.api.forEachNode((node) => {

 ...here is my code that I want to test, but my test is not going inside this forEach loop

    });
});

My test
 describe('validateIfEmptyEditableCells', () => {
        const mockGridApi = new GridApi();
        const cellEditingStoppedEvent = {
            api: mockGridApi,
        };
        const nodes = [
            {
                rowIndex: 0,
                data: {
                    col1: testValue,
                    col2: testValue2,
                },
            },
        ];
        jest.spyOn(mockGridApi, 'forEachNode').mockImplementation(
            (forEach: any) => {
                nodes.forEach((node) => forEach(node));
            }
        );

        const editableColumnsList = ['col1'];

        test('validateIfEmptyEditableCells', () => {
            expect(
                validateIfEmptyEditableCells(
                    (cellEditingStoppedEvent as unknown) as CellEditingStoppedEvent,
                    editableColumnsList
                )
            ).toEqual({ localValidFlag: true, rowDataEdited: [] });
        });


Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
